# Dropdown is a scrolling list - not a dropdown - .Net core MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown

I have a form on a razor page. All of the fields are dropdowns. All of the dropdowns are working correctly except for one.

This one has a lot of if and for statements and disabled separators in it. I'm assuming that's the problem and I've written the code wrong but I've spent a long time banging my head on the keyboard.

The dropdown I'm having a problem with is populating correctly and looks like it should. Instead of a dropdown, though, it looks like a scrolling table. The code setting the dropdown up is the same code I used for the ones that work.

The first div is for a dropdown that's working correctly. The second div is part of the dropdown that's not working. The rest of the code in that div just repeats itself with different times.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="form-group btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block" style="width:9.6em; background-color: whitesmoke" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmpPosition" asp-for="EmpPosition">
        <option>Position</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Positions)
        {
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="@item.Id">@item.PositionName</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="form-group btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block mt-2" style="width:12em; text-align:center; background-color:whitesmoke" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" asp-for="LunchTime">
        <option style="text-align:center">Lunch Time</option>
        @if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 01 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 10)
        {
            <option disabled>_______________________</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item disabled" style="text-align:center" href="#">0400 - 1400</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.fourAM)
            {
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">@item</option>
            }
        }
        @if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 03 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 12)
        {
            <option disabled>_______________________</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item disabled" style="text-align:center" href="#">0600 - 1600</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.sixAM)
            {
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">@item</option>
            }
        }
```

Rendered:

```
<form class="DthdropdownGroup ml-3" action="/Home/CreateLunch" method="post">
<div class="btn-group" style="margin-left:-.5rem">
    <select class="form-group btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block pr-1" style="width:9.6em; padding-left: .2rem; background-color: whitesmoke" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmployeeId" data-val="true" data-val-required="The EmployeeId field is required." name="EmployeeId">
        <option>Dispatcher</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1 form-control" value="2">Jenny</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1 form-control" value="1">Joseph</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1 form-control" value="3">Tammy</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="form-group btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block" style="width:9.6em; background-color: whitesmoke" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmpPosition" data-val="true" data-val-required="The EmpPosition field is required." name="EmpPosition">
        <option>Position</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="5">FC</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="3">FL</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="4">FR</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="1">SO1</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="2">SO2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="form-group btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block mt-2" style="width:12em; text-align:center; background-color:whitesmoke" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="LunchTime" multiple="multiple" name="LunchTime">
        <option style="text-align:center">Lunch Time</option>
            <option disabled="">_______________________</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item disabled" style="text-align:center" href="#">0400 - 1400</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/2/22 08:30</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/2/22 09:00</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/2/22 09:30</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/2/22 10:00</option>
            <option disabled="">_______________________</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item disabled" style="text-align:center" href="#">2000 - 0600</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 01:00</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 01:30</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 02:00</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 02:30</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 03:00</option>
            <option disabled="">_______________________</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item disabled" style="text-align:center" href="#">2200 - 0800</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 03:30</option>
                <option style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="dropdown-item">3/3/22 04:00</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    45 min:<input class="ml-2" style="margin-top:.4em" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The EmpSent field is required." name="EmpSent">
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mt-2 btn-block" style="margin-left:-.5rem; background-color:whitesmoke">Submit</button>
```

VM:

```
using Seating.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Seating.ViewModels
{
    public class ListsVM
    {
        public ListsVM()
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
            Positions = new List<Position>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Dth> Dths { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Break> Breaks { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Lunch> Lunches { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LunchTimes> LunchTime { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int EmpPosition { get; set; }
        public bool EmpSent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also have a screenshot showing what it's looking like when it's run. Thank you all for your help.[image]

Edited to include rendered

Comment: Please show us the **rendered** HTML, not just your `.cshtml` source.

Comment: I suspect something is either setting `multiple` on your `<select>` element when it's rendered (it could be ASP.NET Core doing it because of a `[Display]` attribute on your `LunchTime` property), or it could be scripts, or you could have a CSS rule that's completely overriding its `appearance`.

Comment: Thanks @Dai. I'll edit it to show the other items as well. Sorry about that.

Comment: As I expected, the problem is something is adding `multiple="multiple"` to the `<select>`'s rendered HTML. Check your tag-helpers and viewmodel's property attributes.

Comment: Remove multiple="multiple"  from the second select.

Comment: As others said, your problem caused by the `multiple="multiple"`. Could you please share what's the type of your `LunchTime`? Also, how do you define `ViewBag.fourAM` and `ViewBag.sixAM`?

Comment: @Dai Huh.... you're all right. Taking it out in Dev Tools fixed it. Now I just have to figure out what's causing it. If you want to make it an answer I'll show it accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @TylerJohnson You still haven't posted your view-model class...

Comment: I'm brand new with VM so I may have this wrong. Please let me know. I'll post it now.

Comment: @Rena I work in a large 911 center. Two rules with lunches: Only one person at lunch at a time and you can only sign up for times assigned to your shift. So the controller iterates the active lunches and populates each list with a DateTime type. That list is assigned to a ViewBag. For example, if your shift starts at 0400, the controller will iterate and look for 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 and 10:00. If those times aren't in the database, it's added to the 0400 list and assigned to a ViewBag. The view populates the dropdown based on the current time of day (at 0100 the 0400 list appears in the dropdown)

Comment: @Dai I figured it out. It was a problem with the VM. LunchTimes used to be a db - that's why it's in the top section. I don't have that DB anymore but added a table to lunches called LunchTimes but forgot to change the VM. When I changed it, it started to work perfectly. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: ...I hope you're not saying you're using EF Entity types as ViewModels subject to ASP.NET's model-binding?

Comment: I looked at a lot of examples and took classes. I thought the way I had it was the right way to do it. Again, I'm learning as I go along so I'm sure I'm making mistakes along the way. I'm open to any advice.

Comment: In that case I invite you to see my answer to this question (they're asking about DTOs, but ViewModels in ASP.NET (Core) MVC work the same way as DTOs): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186748/dotnet-api-request-response-classes/71187024#71187024  (note that this advice only applies if you're having ASP.NET populate ViewModels using Model Binding from `<form>` `POST` requests - so if you're only simply _rendering_ EF entity classes to HTML in Razor without using anything like `.TextBoxFor()` or `<input asp-for="">` then you're fine.

Comment: I do want to say that ASP.NET MVC (and ASP.NET Core) both have a **major** design-flaw: there's no way to specify *two different specific types* where one type is a strictly one-way rendering dependency (i.e. a view-model) and the other type is _only_ for two-way form/model binding - so ASP.NET basically forces you to use a single type for both purposes, even though they're fundamentally different things. I have my own homegrown workarounds but they're unpolished. I could talk for hours about why having separate types is a great idea and all the advantages, but alas, my Trello backlog  grows.